# reverse proxy forward to multiple servers sequentially

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, apache2

I have server A and Server B.
I would like to set up a reverse proxy server the takes client requests and forward it to server A and when processed by Server A the Reverse proxy server should forward the request(i.e the response from server A) to Server B and send the response back to Client.

Full Flow :

```
 Client -[Sends a request] --> Reverse proxy --> Server A[Process request]--> 
 Reverse proxy [forward modified request] --> Server B--> Reverse proxy --> Client
```

Is there any way to achieve this with NGINX or apache2 server?

Comment: The question is too broad. May be you want something like auth_request or x-accel-redirect. Or you could end up writing script in lua. But in general it’s not possible.

Comment: If you give a bit more information on what you are trying to achive, we might be able to help. Generally speaking, what you intent to do is fairly normal; server A uses a service on server B in order to resolve the original request. But without more information the solutions range from no work, to programming a virtual services that in turn call A and B before returning.

Comment: Lua script seems a choice, I want to intercept the request and modify payload(by calling some other API service) before sending it to final  server (server B)